# How to change the order of 3 bootstrap columns at small screen size using push and pull?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, push, pull

I have 3 columns using bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
   <div class="col-md-5">2</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
```

they look like this at medium at large size:
[image]

I want them to appear like this at small and x-small size:
[image]

I tried using pull and push

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-push-4">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-pull-5">3</div>
</div>
```

but the result at small is:
[image]
and the order is changed at medium and large sizes not at small

my code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFMTM73UDAWR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case start from mobile

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" style="border:solid 1 px black;">1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-push-4" style="border:solid 1 px black;">3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4" style="border:solid 1 px black;">2</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm using bootstrap for 3 years and this is the first time I know that if I start from mobile will change the results. your code is working exactly like what I want.

Comment: I learned this approach on one of bootstrap lectures, I think edx, they just simply said - always remember - bootstrap mobile first, so change bigger grid not smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col=md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col=md-4">2</div>
  <div class="col=md-4">3</div>
</div>
```

simply remove push and pul
bootstrap goes as mobile first, and if not specified - grid will take all 12 columns
so by specifying col-md-4 for each of the div you are telling to use col-sm-12 and col-xs-12 for smaller screen.

Comment: I want to change the order from 1,2,3 at PC to 1,3,2 at mobile like the second attached image